# Limit value of ${i^∞}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

Can I investigate this limit and if yes, how?  $${i^∞}$$

I am at a loss of ideas and maybe it is undefined?

Comment: Hint:  what is $i^n$ for $n\in \mathbb N$?

Comment: @lulu I think that it "jumps" between positive, negative and imaginary therefore I don't get the picture.

Comment: But that's already enough to tell you that your limit does not exist!

Comment: can you use the formal definition of a limit on the complex plane?  Can you express formally that the series does not permanently become close to any given value?  If you assumed there was a limit, then you should be able to show that the next value has moved away from that limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the sequence $(i^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is the sequence$$i,-1,-i,1,i,-1,-i,1,\ldots$$your sequence diverges.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  The powers of $i$ form a periodic progression among four values.  Convergence means you have some complex number for which the following is true.  For any neighborhood of the number, the sequence eventually enters that neighborhood and never re-exits.

Answer (score 1):

The limit doesn't exist in any event, but you should still be specific about *what* precisely is tending to $\infty$, because you could talk about the limit *set* (i.e., in this case, the set of subsequential limits), and then it matters.  If the exponents are integers, the limit set is $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$.  If the exponents are real numbers, the limit set is the unit circle.  If the exponents are complex numbers (tending to infinity in absolute value) then the limit set is the complex plane.

Answer (score 0):

The convergence of certain sequences is impossible to find if the range is limited to a cycle of a few values. In this case $i^n$ is equal to either $\pm1$ or $\pm i$ with no other values. $\infty$ being the *concept* that it is makes it impossible to determine which of the four solutions would be $\lim_{n\to\infty}{i^n}$.

Other such expressions are $(-1)^n$ which cycles around $1$ and $-1$ in a similar fashion, or $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, whose range is limited to between $-1$ and $1$, without any convergence.